# We can not publish the project in the LG Store

Tags: javascript, responsive-design, photoshop, samsung-smart-tv, lg

designers. Not long ago, we developed a project on WebOS for LG TVs. The project was developed on pure JS, our designers prepared icons for the application for the requirements specified in
http://webostv.developer.lge.com/design/style/icon/ 
3 - already trying to pass verification to publish the project, 3 times ignored due to the fact that:
https://gyazo.com/10339eb0a39755fa08a4a4805cd9cd5c
Although all the icons are made according to their requirements. Has anyone encountered a similar question? And who posted the project on the LG Store? Share your experience, please

Comment: The created icons : https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/folders/1CYzg16LOj6o2w315i_cO0JncJVIsXnwk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot open your drive folder but make sure yours icons have a solid background colour and it is the same you have selected in the appinfo.json (will be overridden during the registration process of the app)

The TV will compose the home panel using your icon (an square PNG icon with solid background colour) and the webos tab (its colour will be set using info in iconColor field from appinfo.json)

I have successfully submitted several apps and I have never had problems like that

**EDIT:**

I've checked your assets and although on the LG website said you should use png files for icons all apps I have submitted in the past have .jpg format for icon and largeIcon (the seller allows you to upload a jpg file for icon during the app registration)

You should try it due jpg files doesn't have alpha layer

Here is a sample appinfo.json for your reference (used for an approved app)

```
"appDescription": "Dummy text for app description",
"icon": "icon.jpg",
"main": "index.html",
"bgImage": "splashScreen.png",
"title": "DummyApp",
"type": "web",
"resolution": "1920x1080",
"version": "1.0.0",
"splashBackground": "splashScreen.png",
"vendor": "DummyAppsInc",
"largeIcon": "largeIcon.jpg",
"iconColor": "#ffffff",
"id": "com.dummypackage.app",
"uiRevision": 3,
"disableBackHistoryAPI": true
```

}

Comment: I give access to your email. Please check,  I will be very grateful to you

Comment: Can you send me your appinfo.json and also your icons?